# Business Use Case and just Use Case

Tags: uml

What's the difference between a **Business Use-Case Model** and a **Use-Case model**? I'm supposed to make both for a website, but I cannot understand what's the difference... Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an alternative description would help.

'Business' and 'System' Use Cases differ in scope. The former encompasses everything the customer and supplier have to do in order to complete the goal.  Some of that may involve a system interaction - but some may not.  As an example, take buying a book online.  Certain aspects will involve be completed online (e.g. browsing available books, placing order).  But some are not: picking the stock, packaging, shipping, signing for receipt of package.

A Business Use Case is a "black box" description of the entire interaction ("Buy Book").  Completing the task means following a business process.  Some of the steps in the process will involve a user-system interaction, some will not.  Where a step does involve a user and a system ("Browse available books") that step is a System Use Case.  Typically there will be a number of System Use Cases for a given Business Use Case.

So do you need both?  It depends on circumstances.

If you're (a) responsible for the complete business scope, and (b) want to document the business capabilities as Use Cases, then a Business UCD and supporting UC definitions is useful.  The steps in the UC description would represent the business process.

If someone else is responsible for the business-level definitions then you probably don't need to.

One final thing: sometimes the two are coincident.  For example: buying an eBook.  The Business Need is for the customer to be able to get their book.  The entire thing could be delivered in a single system interaction (select book, pay, receive download) - and so could be covered by a single System Use Case.  So the Business- and System Use Cases are equivalent.

hth.

Comment: Mm... still having troubles figuring those out. I'm working on a project with a social network (non-existent, but think something like facebook). The User can Upload pics, make albums, keep a journal - will those be part of the business UC or the system UC? Should I go deeper like uploading pics will include naming, organizing, etc?

Comment: Since its all online you're going to have overlap.  In that case I wouldn't get worked up about the difference - it's not really relevant.  The important thing is to make sure you capture UCs at the level of User Goals.  You already list some: Upload Pictures, Make Album, Create Journal, Add Journal Entry, etc.  Those are the "Business" UCs.  If you need to capture any of the steps as separate UCs you can deem them "System" UCs (login/logout are common examples).  More importantly however: since all the interactions are online, don't get hung up on it. (ctd...)

Comment: (...ctd). Focus on making sure you capture the User's goals, document them, and decompose into lower level UCs if you need to (but only if you need to).  hth.

Comment: Thank you. I already started doing so, but at least now I know I'm on the right way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

***A business UC*** (use case) contains absolutely no technical detail. And you need to step back a way to see the business need. So business UCs may be something like:

- Manage Photos Online
- Create Personal Log Entries
- Interact With Other Users Online
- Share Photos With Other Users

Notice none of this says anything about how it will be done. At this point it's pretty much a listing of needed functionality put into action-subject-qualifier format.

You can put them into a use case model with the actors and you have a very useful set of high-level business UCs. Finish spec'ing out UCs with their pre- and post-conditions and such for low-level business UCs. But at this poing the detail of the paths aren't known.

***A system UC*** contains the system-level perspective on those business UCs. So, while Manage Photos Online may describe the need to upload photos and group them into albums, the system UCs may actually turn into:

- Upload Image (with paths for uploading, naming, cropping and deleting)
- Manage Album (with paths for creating, adding images and removing images)

Here we've gotten into technical detail. The business may be thinking in terms of storing and swapping photos, but you know that there's little difference in how the system will perceive and handle photos and bitmap images. You've started thinking about just what's involved in uploading images and what the user may need to do with the images.

I hope this helped.